# PHP Memory leak with magic __set

Tags: php, oop

I recently start an optimisation of my Collection class and I found a memory leak. An exemple of code :

```
class anObject {}

$array = array();
for ($i=0; $i < 5000; $i++) {
    $obj = new anObject();
    for ($j = 0; $j <5; $j++) {
        $obj->{'test'.$j} = $j;
    }
    $array[] = $obj;
}

echo memory_get_usage();
// 3548328
unset($array);

class anObjetWithSetter {
    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->{$key} = $value;
    }
}

$array = array();
for($i=0; $i < 5000; $i++) {
    $obj = new anObjetWithSetter();
    for ($j = 0; $j <5; $j++) {
        $obj->{'test'.$j} = $j;
    }
    $array[] = $obj;
}

echo memory_get_usage();
// 5708440
```

Can anyone have an idea on this memory leak?

Comment: It's not a memory leak. If you comment out everything above `class anObjetWithSetter` then you get the same memory usage from only running the second loop.

Comment: Rename `anObjectWithSetter` to `anObjectWithOneMoreSymbolToStoreInMemory`. :)

Comment: @bassxzero If I comment the setter, I have the same class! Why the setter is using more memory for the same result ?

Comment: @Narf I know it's a joke, but it's not the symbol that costs memory! The method magic _set costs double of memory ... it's huge. I don't understand why

Comment: @YohannTilotti You're asking me how PHP was implemented, to which i reply I didn't write it so I don't know. At the very least I know that It takes more memory to hold classes with functions vs classes without functions. But for all I know PHP could have some special optimization for  classes with no body.

Comment: @bassxzero You can add functions in the class anObjetWithSetter, this don't change the size of memory used. And yes, this question is linked with PHP core.

Comment: Maybe __set magic use ReflectionClass or something else...

Comment: @YohannTilotti adding other magic methods like `__toString()` does increase the memory used to hold the instances. So maybe it's some special form of optimization. If you really care about it that much then you may want to use `memory_get_usage(true)` instead of `memory_get_usage()`. Also, I believe that memory is allocated in blocks that are double what is needed to prevent a lot of system calls for memory, just an fyi to keep in mind.

Comment: @YohannTilotti It was a joke, but a "funny because it's true" joke ... Though, you are correct in that `__set()` specifically raises the memory consumption more than `__get()` for example. Looking at the code, it looks like PHP guards against `__set()` triggering itself while trying to assign `$this->$key`, and it does that by copying the object pointer. But it's much more nuanced than that and I'm not really familiar with it, so I can't give a definitive answer.

Comment: @bassxzero It's the same conclusion with `memory_get_usage(true)`.